# Repetição de Código

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tendo problema com a repetição de código na minha classe de conexão CURL, a classe está sendo declarada da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
if (!defined("ROOT_PATH")) define("ROOT_PATH", dirname(__FILE__, 2));

require_once ROOT_PATH."/helpers/Helper.php";

class PhabricatorModel
{
    const TOKEN = "api.token=api-...";

    public function add($parameters)
    {
        $channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pb-dc.com/api/maniphest.edit");
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, self::TOKEN.$parameters);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($channel);
        if (curl_errno($channel)) {
            return false;
        }

        curl_close($channel);

        return $result;
    }

    public function consultProject($project)
    {
        $channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pb-dc.com/api/project.query");
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, self::TOKEN."names[]=".$project);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $result = Helper::convert_array(json_decode(curl_exec($channel)));
        if (curl_errno($channel)) {
            return false;
        }

        curl_close($channel);

        return $result;
    }

    public function consultStory($story)
    {
        $channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pb-dc.com/api/maniphest.query");
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, self::TOKEN."status=status-open&fullText=".$story);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $result = Helper::convert_array(json_decode(curl_exec($channel)));
        if (curl_errno($channel)) {
            return false;
        }

        curl_close($channel);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Se notar o mesmo item de `curl_init` nos 3 métodos e eu queria remover essa repetição, não só no `curl_init` mas também em outras partes.

Comment: maioria dos casos o curl não resulta em nada se não utilizar `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false`. tenho conhecimento básico. talvez seja isso

Comment: @Guilherme não entendi muito bem o que você quis me passar, poderia me explicar mais ?

Comment: Teus três métodos são muito parecidos em estrutura, você poderia fazer um método único e utilizar a estrutura de switch/case para tratar as partes que são diferentes.

Comment: @GiovanniNunes a ideia é que com o tempo esse código seja evoluído, e para leitura e entendimento um switch/case não ficaria legal pra isso.

Comment: Crie um novo método para inicialização, assim `$channel` virará `$this->channel` e coloque lá CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER e CURLOPT_POST que são iguais nos três casos (mas você ainda pode alterá-los dentro do método sempre que precisar). Vou colocar um exemplo disto aqui nas respostas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trate a variável `$channel` como um atributo da classe e crie um método privado específico para inicializá-la com os valores que já se repetem lá dentro, algo assim:

```
class PhabricatorModel
{
        const TOKEN = "api.token=api-...";

        // o que é comum fica aqui...
        private function curl_init(){
            $this->channel = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        }

        // o que é específico fica num método próprio...
        public function add($parameters) {
            $this->curl_init();
            curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pb-dc.com/api/maniphest.edit");
            curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, self::TOKEN.$parameters);
            if (curl_errno($this->channel)){
                $result = false;
            } else {
                $result = curl_exec($this->channel);
            }
            curl_close($self->channel);
            return $result;
        }
        // alterei a lógica no final para evitar surpresas.

        // ...
```

E a mesma coisa seria feita nos outros métodos.

Answer (score 0):

## Extração de método

Tente criar um novo método que contém a parte que se repete e passe como parâmetro os valores que variam nas chamadas da biblioteca curl.

```
     private function configCurl($url, $token)
     {

        $channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        return $channel;

     }
```

Depois basta usar o método no lugar do código repetido e trabalhar com a referência de curl (agora retornada pelo método), assim como você está fazendo.